# How do I simplify this solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, return, list-comprehension

The function 'conjunctions'  recevies a nested list 'word_list'. This list contains a number of sublists, each a list of words, such as:
`[["Tom", "Laurel", "Merkel"], ["Jerry","Hardy", "Macron"]]`

All the sublists have the same number of words in them. The function must return a list of strings, where each element in a position is an "and" conjunction of all the elements in the same position in all the sublists.

For example:
`conjunctions([["Tom", "Laurel", "Merkel"],["Jerry","Hardy", "Macron"]]`

should return

`['Tom and Jerry', 'Laurel and Hardy', 'Merkel and Macron']`

and

`conjunctions([["one", "apples"],["two","oranges"],["three","bananas"]]`

should return

`['one and two and three', 'apples and oranges and bananas']`

For this practice exercise I had to add different word conjunctions.
Is there any simpler/cleaner way of doing this, you are only allowed to use list comprehension.

Additionally how would I go about making it more robust e.g. allowing various length lists to be entered?(not to fussed about receiving answers for this however)

'''

def conjunctions(word_list):

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

answer = []

if len(word_list) == 3:
    for i in word_list:
        #print(i[0])
        list1.append((i[0]))
        list2.append((i[1]))
    answer.append(list1[0] + " and " + list1[1] + " and " + list1[2])
    answer.append(list2[0] + " and " + list2[1] + " and " + list2[2])

elif len(word_list) ==2: 
    for i in word_list:
        #print(i[2])
        list1.append((i[0]))
        list2.append((i[1]))
        list3.append((i[2]))
    answer.append(list1[0] + " and " + list1[1])
    answer.append(list2[0] + " and " + list2[1])
    answer.append(list3[0] + " and " + list3[1])

return answer
```

'''

**Input:**

```py
conjunctions([["one", "apples"],["two","oranges"],["three","bananas"]])

conjunctions([["Tom", "Laurel", "Merkel"], ["Jerry","Hardy", "Macron"]])
```

**Output:**

```py
['one and two and three', 'apples and oranges and bananas']

['Tom and Jerry', 'Laurel and Hardy', 'Merkel and Macron']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def conjunctions(lst):
    return list(' and '.join(words) for words in zip(*lst))

print(conjunctions([["Tom", "Laurel", "Merkel"],["Jerry","Hardy", "Macron"]]))
print(conjunctions([["one", "apples"],["two","oranges"],["three","bananas"]]))
```

**Output**

```
['Tom and Jerry', 'Laurel and Hardy', 'Merkel and Macron']
['one and two and three', 'apples and oranges and bananas']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
conjunctions = lambda L: list(map(lambda *names: ' and '.join(names), *L))
print(conjunctions([["one", "apples"],["two","oranges"],["three","bananas"]]))
```

Outputs

```py
['one and two and three', 'apples and oranges and bananas']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in four lines (and probably less):

```
lst1 = [["Tom", "Laurel", "Merkel"],["Jerry","Hardy", "Macron"]]
lst2 = [["one", "apples"],["two","oranges"],["three","bananas"]]
def conjunctions(lst):
    final_list = []
    for idx,name in enumerate(lst[0]):
        final_list.append(' and '.join([i[idx] for i in lst]))
    return final_list
```

Output of `conjunctions(lst1)`:

```
['Tom and Jerry', 'Laurel and Hardy', 'Merkel and Macron']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```py
twoDArray = [["one", "apples"],["two","oranges"], ["three","bananas"]]

answer = [0] * len(twoDArray[0])

for i, array in enumerate(twoDArray):
  for j, value in enumerate(array):
    if (answer[j] == 0):
      answer[j] = value
    else:
      answer[j] = answer[j] + " and " + value

print(answer)
```

Try it out https://repl.it/repls/RightJointOutliers

We can initialize an empty `answer` array to the length of the first array in `twoDArray`.

```py
answer = [0] * len(twoDArray[0])
```

Now we loop through `twoDArray` and the values within each array in `array`.

```py
for i, array in enumerate(twoDArray):
  for j, value in enumerate(array):
```

We use `j` the index of inner for loop to determine which index in our `answer` array we are setting.

If the value at index `j` has not been set yet we want to set its `value`.
Otherwise, we will append to the `value` that exists at the index.

```py
    if (answer[j] == 0):
      answer[j] = value
    else:
      answer[j] = answer[j] + " and " + value
```